# How can I change a Discord channel name using nodeJS and discordJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm coding my first discord bot with node.js and discord.js.

The main goal is to give information about a Minecraft server via Discord.

I want to have a channel that every some time, updates its name to:

> There are [x] active players in this server.

I have a variable that updates every `1 minute` with the number of people currently playing.

How can I update a channel name knowing its ID?

I checked the discord.js documentation but I'm a beginner in JS and I don't fully understand what I have to do.

Comment: Have you got a basic bot running so far? This is the method you want: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=setName

Comment: Yes, my bot is running and i have a command that sends a message with the number of players in the server. Thanks for the link, but i don't really know how to implement that to my code. Where do I have to include the channel ID here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the bare minimum to set the guild name. I imagine your bot will need specific permisons to be able to do so thought. Make sure to have a play about with all the methods in the docs!

```
var Discord = require('discord.js');
var client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', ()=>{
    let guild = client.guilds.get( GUILD_ID_HERE );
    let channel = guild.channels.get( CHANNEL_ID_HERE )
    channel.setName('My Cool new guild name')
})

client.login( YOUR_BOT_TOKEN );
```